# Remove unwanted outline on raster export

Tags: qgis

I'm having an issue whereby the SVG I export via print composer doesn't reflect what I see in QGIS. My exported SVG image collects additional grey borders around the outermost boundaries of the raster.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here I'm having the same problem with a different raster, on a different computer. This is QGIS Release 2.18. You can see my workflow below.

[image]

Exporting to SVG or PDF using print composer has a grey border each time

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your project structure, but the svg export from qgis does have clipping issues. I'd try exporting as pdf and opening that in your vector illustration editor instead.

Comment: @ndawson Thanks, its still the same with pdf. I get the same borders even if I export without clipping. I've added more detail to my question